# Idea to avoid identical URLSession-dataTask - but getting the data for both when the first comes back

Tags: swift, networking, fetch, urlsession

Using a URLSession.dataTask (with a completion-block) to fetch some data from the network, I am struggling with the following:

- The data-task takes time (since network is slow for example)
- during this time, the user might ask for the data again (by clicking the download button again or by segueing to another VC that needs similar data - or by many applications where this behaviour is an advantage)

Now, normally I would just follow the user's orders and set up the same dataTask a second time.

But isn't there a way of "not starting a second dataTask" but rather "use the incoming data from the first one" and provide its data to both, the first (that is still waiting) and the second (that only waited a short amount of time.

I came up with the following Code (that might look a bit messy).
The idea is that every incoming datatask brings an IDKey. And if a download with the same key is still out there to fetch, then the second one waits.

Unfortunately, the code does not work since it somehow blocks threads in the App that call this mehtod.

Any help on how to implement this "not doing the same network call again if already out there" idea.

```
class UrlSessionDataTaskSingletonTool: NSObject {

    static let shared = UrlSessionDataTaskSingletonTool()

    private var localData: Data?
    private var localError: Error?
    private let groupSharedTool = DispatchGroup()
    var IDDict: [String:Int] = ["":0]
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    func receiveData(IDKey: String, request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> () ) {

        // check if IDDict already contains a key named IDKey
        if self.IDDict.contains(where: { (key, _) -> Bool in
            return (key == IDKey)
        }) {
            self.IDDict[IDKey] = self.IDDict[IDKey]! + 1
        } else {
            self.IDDict[IDKey] = 1
            groupSharedTool.enter()
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    let error = DataTaskError.urlError(reason: "Could not fetch data inside shareTool")
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                } else {
                    if let data = data {
                        self.localData = data
                        self.localError = nil
                        self.IDDict.removeValue(forKey: IDKey)
                    } else {
                        self.localError = DataTaskError.urlError(reason: "Could not fetch data inside shareTool")
                        self.localData = nil
                        self.IDDict.removeValue(forKey: IDKey)
                    }
                }
                    self.groupSharedTool.leave()
                    self.semaphore.signal()
            }
            task.resume()
        }

        groupSharedTool.notify(queue: .global()) {
            completionHandler(self.localData, self.localError)
        }

        let noWait = self.semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + .milliseconds(1000 * 10))

        if noWait == .success {
            completionHandler(self.localData, self.localError)
        } else if noWait == .timedOut {
            self.localError = DataTaskError.urlError(reason: "Timeout Error")
            completionHandler(nil, self.localError)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you first need some state management keeping track of whether there is a request in progress or not. Second, you need a way of informing multiple targets/delegates if and when that data comes in (you could have an array of closures; you could have an array of delegates/observers; you could use notification center to just inform whomever cares that the new data has arrived, etc.).

Comment: But I'd lose that semaphore stuff. I'd lose the dispatch group stuff, too. Both of those are not needed and add unnecessarily confusion here.